# .append in Jquery shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

```
$("#clckjson").click(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("fuelj.json", function(data) {
      $(data).each(function(i, item) {

        console.log(item.stationID);
        var $table = $('<table>');
        $table.append("<thead>").children("thead")
          .append("<tr/>").children("tr").append("<th>StationID</th><th>Distance</th><th>Address</th><th>H24</th><th>Phones</th><th>FuelTypeID</th><th>FuelPrice</th><th>PriceTimestamp</th><th>FuelName</th>");
        var $tbody = $table.append("<tbody/>").children("tbody");

        $tbody.append("<tr/>").children("tr:last")
          .append("<td>").append(item.stationID)
          .append("<td>").append(item.distance)
          .append("<td>").append(item.address)
          .append("<td>").append(item.value)
          .append("<td>").append(item.phone)
          .append("<td>").append(item.fuelTypeID)
          .append("<td>").append(item.price)
          .append("<td>").append(item.priceTimeStamp)
          .append("<td>").append(item.fuel);


        $table.appendTo('#stationtb');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I have an html page with a div a button and a table inside and with jQuery I want to add cells dynamically with JSON objects in the table and when I press the button everything to show up. The problem now is that when I press the button the table shows up just fine but the items I try to append do not show at all and `console.log` shows `undefined`. May I have some help?

Comment: You're not appending to the tds.  Look at the process you go through to append the trs and then append to the trs (similar to the tbody and thead appending).  You broke your process when you got to the tds.

Comment: Those append lines. are not doing what you think it is doing

Comment: I would highly recommend trying to remove the creation of markup from your javascript and use a template instead.  If your application is doing this a lot, you should also look into possible incorporating a templating library as well.

Comment: Also, your document ready is pointless, as it's in a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

If data is an array, you need to correct the way to [iterate it](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
```